# Breakpoint does not belong to any class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging, breakpoints

In a some cases android studio stopped debugging process.

I have restart ide, emulator, but problem still appeared

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th first of all check app level build.gradle file

**1.** In a buildTypes `debuggable` property must be true

```
debug / release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
        }
```

**2.** If the problem not solves restart `adb` server
`adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Answer (score 18):

Try to clean the project and rebuild. It worked for me in Android Studio.
You can find cleaning the project in Build tab.

Comment: Clean and rebuild did not work for me. I had to close Android Studio delete build folders, .idea and .gradle folders. Maybe invalidate cache/restart would have work too.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to right-click the file in the *Project tree* and select `Mark as Plain Text` then `Mark as Kotlin` from the same menu.

Comment: Much less time-consuming than the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

Only after restarting `adb server` helps to fix problem

Open Command promt and go to android sdk>platform-tools>

execute `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: `adb kill-server && adb start-server` is the command. `adb reboot` reboots the device

Comment: Doesn't help. Even the infamous android combo: `rm -rf ~/.gradle`, `find $PROJECT_ROOT -name build |xargs rm -rf` & "invalidate&restart" did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. It was somehow caused by `kotlinx.serialization`, possibly combined with data binding (as it also misbehaved in a strange way).

Basically having any class annotated with `@Serializable` in a file caused the `Breakpoint does not belong to any class` error for any line within that file.

Removing the class and doing the holy combo of android studio troubleshooting ( `rm -rf ~/.gradle`, `find $PROJECT_ROOT -name build |xargs rm -rf` and "File / invalidate&restart" ) solved the problem for a particular file.

The problem is likely caused by some of the dependencies having slightly incompatible versions, and to my knowledge there is no reliable way of figuring out the working combination of the said version.